# What causes an IBM Domino server to throw away compiled java code

Tags: lotus-domino

I've created a couple of servlets in an NSF. In future I'll just use the OSGi plugin framework which is much better.  My servlets work fine but occasionally will stop working until the project is rebuilt. From the log I believe the compiled java is being deleted. This could coincide with colleagues opening the database in designer. Does anyone know what triggers will cause the Domino server or designer to delete compiled java contained within an NSF?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether other developers have Build Automatically switched on. If they do, it could be rebuilding the .class files for all Java files. The other thing to check is whether "Refresh entire application when design changes" is ticked in xsp.properties (xsp.application.forcefullrefresh). That will definitely do it.

I tend to keep Build Automatically switched off for this kind of reason. I've seen my beans disappear because someone else did a build on the Java files.

It not typically a problem in an Eclipse environment, I don't think, because you don't tend to be touching live code in Eclipse. But an NSF can be live code.

Comment: I should have said that I'd checked that each one had build automatically turned off. As you say xsp.properties doesn't by default "Refresh entire application when design changes".

I think the best answer is use OSGi :-)

Comment: "Refresh entire application when design changes" is from 8.5.3, so it may be related to server version. "This could coincide with colleagues opening the database" may be related to their designer version.